# How to create while loop with <READER>?

Tags: perl

I have this assignment where we're expected to loop a child process into a reader until it returns as UNDEF. I'm still very new to programming, so I'm having a difficult time understanding how the fork and WRITER,READER functions work so it's made this task more difficult. I'm not quite sure how to implement this loop?

Here is exactly what's asked:

> Have the parent go into a loop asking the user for a message to send, until the user presses enter with no message ($msg eq “\n”).  Have the child go into a loop reading the pipe and printing the result until reading the pipe returns UNDEF, just like getting to the end of a file.  The loop would start something like this: while  ($msg= ) {...}

The first loop was simple enough, the second loop involving the child process is what confuses me. I have absolutely no idea how to complete this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
 use strict;

    pipe(READER, WRITER);
    autoflush WRITER 1;

    print "\n";

my $pid = fork();

if ($pid){
    &userInput($pid);
}else{ 
    &userOutput();
}
sub userInput{
    close READER;

    my $child = $_[0];
    print "Parent Process $$ Created Child Process $child\n";
    my $user_input = "...";
    while ($user_input ne "\n"){
    print "Enter your name: ";
     $user_input = <STDIN>;

    #If user input is't "\n" do:
    print "Parent PID $$ received: $user_input\n";
    print WRITER $user_input;
    # and then recursively call myself
    waitpid($child, 0);
    print "Child Process $child has finished\n";
}
}

sub userOutput{
    close WRITER;
    my $child = $$;
    my $result = <READER>;
    print "Entering Child Process with id $child\n";
    print "RECEIVED $result FROM PIPELINE\n";
}
```

Comment: `autoflush WRITER 1;` should be written `WRITER->autoflush(1);`. Don't forget to `use warnings;`. Leave out the `&` when calling subroutines. Check if the fork succeeded: `my $pid = fork // die "fork failed: $!";` Use lexical filehandles not global barewords, and check if the pipe succeeded: `pipe(my $reader, my $writer) or die "pipe failed: $!";`

Answer (score 2):

Use another `while` as you did in `UserInput`. Both are reading from input and you use the same ideas to accomplish both tasks:

```
while( <READER> ) {
...
}
```

The line input operator (`<READER>`) returns undef when there's nothing more to read (i.e. the other side closed the connection). That stops the `while` automatically since `undef` is a false value.

This is the same thing the problem told you to do. Now fill in the statements that belong in the loop and you are there.